# Measurable sets modulo measure 0 and boolean algebra clarification

Tags: measure-theory

This is a clarification question on the meaning of a phrase.

I'm reading through Manin's "Mathematical Logic for Mathematicians," and he defines a boolean algebra $B$ as a set that include distinguished $0$ and $1$ with an operation $'$ of rank 1, two operations $\land$ and $\lor$ of rank 2, with the following axioms:

1. $(A')' = A$.
2. $\land$ and $\lor$ are associative and commutative.
3. $\land$ and $\lor$ distribute over each other.
4. DeMorgan-like laws for $\land$ and $\lor$.
5. Both $\land$ and $\lor$ are idempotent.
6. $1 \land a = a$.
7. $0 \lor a = a$.

This is not the first time I've seen a boolean algebra, but what confuses me is his word choice in the following passage:

> An example is the algebra of measurable subsets (modulo measure-zero subsets) of a probability space $M$ with standard set-theoretic interpretations of the operations.

I've not done any measure theory, and while I've encountered questions involving measurable sets in some geometry, I don't understand what he means by "modulo measure-zero subsets."

Is it just that he identifies all measure-zero subsets to be the same, i.e., the element $0$?

Comment: Two measurable sets are equivalent if their symmetric difference is measure $0$.

Comment: @DonThousand So if I'm interpreting your response correctly, taking the measurable subsets modulo measure-zero subsets is the same as saying "we identify any two sets which have measure 0 symmetric difference"?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely it.

Comment: @DonThousand Thanks so much!

Comment: Actually, all measurable sets, by definition, form a $\sigma$-algebra which is a Boolean algebra. We can quotient out by the *Boolean ideal* of sets of measure $0$, this is the same what DonThousand commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding @DonThousand 's comment as an answer. Your interpretation is correct.

The relation between sets that contains pairs whose symmetric difference is of measure $0$ is an equivalence relation. The boolean operations naturally work on the blocks of the partition corresponding to that equivalence relation. The set of those blocks is the example referred to.

Comment: Thank you for the expansion. I have a question relevant to the idea that boolean operations naturally work on the quotient set. Manin says that identities of the form "$(A\mod 0) \land (B\mod 0) = (A \cap B)\mod 0$ do not extend to infinite families. I am not yet confident in my understanding of measure to find a counterexample to $\land_{i} (A_i\mod 0) = (\cap_{i} A_i)\mod 0$ so that this claim makes sense. Is a nested sequence of intervals a counterexample? The intersection should be a single point, but taken mod 0 is $\varnothing$.

Comment: To clarify, the relevant boolean algebra takes $\land$ to mean $\cap$ over measurable subsets modulo measure-zero subsets.

Comment: The intersection of nested intervals works just fine. But consider the set of sets each of which omits just one point. Each of those is equivalent to the whole space modulo sets of measure $0$, but their intersection is empty.

Comment: A much more jarring example! Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure the nested intervals are  a counterexample. That depends on the definition of infinite meets (which is obvious for infinite intersections). The example I did provide depends on uncountability. I wonder if there's a countable example.

Comment: Why is it not a counterexample? Maybe not in general, but in this case I'm looking at the specific interpretation $\land \Rightarrow \cap$, so for such an interpretation this should work as a counterexample... right?

Comment: How is the infinite meet defined? If the set of lattice elements has a unique greatest lower bound, that will be it. The greatest lower bound of the equivalence classes of the nested intervals shrinking to a point is indeed the class of sets of measure $0$, so not a counterexample. (I think.)

Comment: I see your side, but I think I'm not convinced. Is the meet over the measure of the sets, or the sets themselves? If it's over the measure of the sets, it's the infimum of a decreasing nonzero sequence, which indeed gives us 0. If it's over the sets themselves, then I still think that the limit should be $\{1\}$, since we may consider the infinite intersection of nested intervals mod measure 0 to just be the infinite intersection of intervals. I have little experience with lattices, so this clarification would be helpful.

Comment: The meet is defined just in the lattice, as the greatest lower bound when it exists. In this case that's $\{1\}$. but that is equivalent to the empty set modulo sets of measure $0$.

Comment: I see now. Now I understand why it's not obvious whether or not there's a countable example.